# wxPython - Tooltips for notebook tabs

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, tooltip, wxnotebook

I'm creating a GUI using wxPython that uses the wx.Notebook widget.
Since I removed the labels on the Notebook tabs for design purposes,
I would like to add tooltips **for each tab individually** that show
the tab's purpose.

I thought I could use the `AddPage()` method of the Notebook class. But it only returns bool values, so that I cannot use the `SetToolTip()` method for either tab.
How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that is built-in to the `wx.Notebook` widget. You could probably do it yourself by binding to `wx.EVT_MOTION` and checking you mouse's position to determine when to set a tooltip.

The `AUINotebook` might be a better choice since it has a `TabHitTest` method. Someone on the wxPython group mentioned a way to add tooltips to it here: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/setting-a-tooltip-on-auinotebook-tab-td5548750.html

Here's the code they ended up using in the mouse over event handler:

```
def OnMouseOver(self, evt):
    """ mouse over on a tab """

    desc = None
    n    = self.GetSelection()
    if n != -1:
        page_info = self._tabs.GetPage(n)
        ctrl, ctrl_idx = self.FindTab(page_info.window)
        if ctrl:
            ctrl.SetToolTipString(desc)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give AUINotebook a shot.